# I can't find my hard drive to make a backup of it

Tags: hard-drive

2 weeks ago my computer stopped working. I thought it wasn't going to work anymore but I heard about ubuntu and I burned it in a DVD and try to restore or "backup" all my files and my information which is so valuable. Is there a way to do it? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Is your hard disk visible in the System BIOS first?  If yes, then by loading your system with Ubuntu Live DVD, you can coonect an external harddisk and recover your contents from your internal harddisk.

Regards
PK